# docker container set as Local DNS does not resolve nslookup command or display local webpaga in NGINX container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, docker-compose, dns

I am trying to set a local development enviroment with nginx docker and local DNS containers, once I bring docker compose up and typed commands it response with:

```
$ nslookup ns.main.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

$dig @127.0.0.1 ns.main.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.2-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.1 ns.main.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 38715
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: e9ba5744ce2779c601000000633878c753c784e7d4f38f3e (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns.main.com.           IN  A

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sat Oct 01 11:28:39 CST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 68
```

The test domain is not resolved and test page is not access, there is a step missing for create the environment,
The OS is  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.
Because local DNS conflict with network real DNS after running `docker compose build` it has to disable local resolution service with:

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
```

then run `docker compose up -d`
Noted that PC is not able to access internet.

docker compose file is:

```
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/html/:/usr/share/nginx/html/
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/

  dns:
    build:
      context: ./dns/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 53:53
      - 53:53/udp
    volumes:
      - ./dns/named.conf:/etc/bind/named.conf
      - ./dns/zone/:/etc/bind/zone/
    command: named -c /etc/bind/named.conf -g -u named
```

the structure and files for environment are:

[image]

the file details in services DNS:

`Dockerfile` file:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add bind openrc
RUN rc-update -u named
```

`named.conf` file:

```
options {
  directory "var/bind";
  allow-transfer { "none"; };
  allow-query { any; };
  listen-on { any; };
};

zone "main.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zone/main.com";
};

zone "secondary.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zone/secondary.com";
};
```

`dns/zone/main.com` file:

```
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA ns.main.com. hostmaster.main.com. (
                    202      ; Serial
                    600      ; Refresh
                    3600     ; Retry
                    1209600)  ; Expire
                    ; 3600)    ; Negative Cache TTL

@       IN      NS      ns.main.com.
ns      IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

`dns/zone/secondary.com` file:

```
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA ns.secondary.com. hostmaster.secondary.com. (
                    202      ; Serial
                    600      ; Refresh
                    3600     ; Retry
                    1209600)  ; Expire
                    ;3600)    ; Negative Cache TTL

@       IN      NS      ns.secondary.com.
ns      IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

-- NGINX service:
`Dockerfile` file:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./html /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps
```

`nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name main.com ns.main.com *.main.com;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/main;
        index index.html;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name secondary.com ns.secondary.com *.secondary.com;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/secondary;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

`nginx/html/main/index.html` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Docker Nginx</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Hello from Nginx container!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

`nginx/html/secondary/index.html` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Docker Nginx</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Hello from secondary</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

for access internet again it needs to rollback commands and deactivat/activate network/WIFI with:

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you want to use a custom dns server? Just put you names into the hosts file, and turn back resolved.

Comment: it is for test feature in NGINX, simulated DNS resolution for example from *.main.com to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming but `SERVFAIL` from a DNS server is a pretty severe condition, and you should have details in its logfile on what did not work.

Comment: If I do not disable `systemd-resolved` the `SERVFAIL` messages is received from external DNS.  When it is disable nslookup does not goes externally and temporized attemp.

Answer (score 0):

When we do not disable `systemd-resolved` service, our PC goes to internet, because my domain name test is not registed then from outside our PC does not receive any resolved IP to routing packages so `SERVFAIL` is displayed.

Once we disable `systemd-resolved` we could access to local DNS service dockerized however locally DNS is solved with file in `/etc/resolv.conf` which has this default content:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

Since PC cannot resolved nslookup command, temporized and failed because server could not be reached, it is dockerized in localhost.

My solution during test is:

1. Disable local resolution service.
2. Add localhost to `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

3. Add localhost and external DNS to interface `edns0` (WIFI in my case) for having external DNS resolution too.
4. Deactivate/activate interface.
5. nslookup is OK and my APP in `docker compose` NGINX service is reacheable.

Once I finish my work I can enable `systemd-resolved` and deactive and active  interface.  Also PC back to default once it is booting.